# Jenkins Xcode plugin not finding provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, jenkins, provisioning-profile

I'm having an issue with the [jenkins Xcode plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/xcode-plugin). It's not finding the provisioning profiles on the build machine even though they are there. If I log into the box as the same user that jenkins is using and I open the Xcode project I can select the provisioning profile an create the IPA manually. But when jenkins tries it says

```
MyApp requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
```

Here is how I have the code signing settings specified in the plugin. I am using the provisioning profile's UUID to identify it. I have also the full path to the the file. Neither seem to work.

[image]

System specs:

```
macOS: 13.5.1
Jenkins: 2.414.1
Xcode: 14.3.1
Xcode plugin Version: 2.0.17-565.v1c48051d46ef
```

Any ideas what's going on here?